# File delete on selenium grid failed

Tags: file, selenium-webdriver, testing, ui-automation, selenium-grid

When I run a test on the remote machine using Selenium Grid from my local machine, it downloads a file on the remote machine. However, I encounter a failure when attempting to delete the downloaded file because the deletion operation is being performed on my local machine instead of the remote machine.

Please help me to delete a file in remote server.